# Very dark video streaming from raspberry?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

Respected StackOverflow community,

I am trying to stream video from raspberry pi 4B using python-OpenCV code( camera streamer run on raspberry pi and camera receiver run on my pc windows 10 Pycharm IDE.

unfortunately, when I try to run the code the image displayed is very dark. when I use different code the video streams just fine.

can anyone suggest to me what should I do to make this code working?

I am using Opencv 3.4 on both my pc and RPi.
and python 3.x

Edit1:
I run main.py on my Rpi and camerareceiver.py on my computer what I don't understand why will the image be so dark. is there something wrong with windows or encoding part of the code.

Could it be a windows problem . like when i tried to control the car remotely windows created a delay.

[image: Dark image output on pycharm]

Comment: all the network stuff is irrelevant. please remove/simplify. illustrate your problem with the least amount of code. why did you not show how you access the camera?

Comment: I have updated the post @ChristophRackwitz.

Comment: Save the image to disk as a JPEG immediately after you acquire it and look at the JPEG. If it is already dark, you can remove all the network send and receive stuff from your question and make it a *"Minimal Complete Reproducible Example"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out how to solve it hope it helps other people stuck with similar problem.

adjusting the frame rate and shutter speed did the trick for me .. my shutter speed was too high which resulted in dark image so i reduced it